# MySQL or SQLite for live messages and notifications

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am going to build a website which will provide to the clients the ability to live chat user to user and also implement a notification system (for new updates, messages, events e.t.c). The primary database is going to be MySQL.

But i was thinking to release some "pressure" from the main database MySQL and instead of saving the chat messages and notifications into MySQL, create a personal SQLite for each client where the messages and notifications will be stored which as a result will leave MySQL do other more important queries. Each client can see only his/her messages and notifications so only he/she will open/read/write/update the corresponding SQLite database.

I think creating individual SQLite databases for each client is like partitioning the tables (messages, notifications) by user_id if they were stored in MySQL. So f.e: instead of quering each time through all the clients notifications in order to find the one which are for user with id:5, we just open his personal SQLite database which will contain ofc much fewer records (only his records).

Now to the question part:

As i said the queries will be simple. Just some selects with 1 or 2 where clauses (mostly on indexes) and some ordering. Since this is the first time i am going to use SQLite i am wondering:

**1)** Will this method (individual SQLite instead of MySQL) practically work in case of perfomance?

**2)** Which method will still perform better after some time when they will begin getting bigger and bigger? SQLite or MySQL?

**3)** Does SQLite have any memory limits which will make it run slower in time?

Whats your opinions on this method?

Comment: If this is *live* chat, why do you want to persist the messages ? Unless you want to archive them for later retrieval ? At any rate, this looks like premature optimization. Create a simple system with only one MySQL database, see what performance issues you run into, and then only think about optimizing. By experience, MySQL is pretty much enough by itself for this, unless you aim for thousands of simultaneous users.

Comment: Also, "quering each time through all the clients notifications" this is not true in practice because the proper use of indexes will prevent full scans of tables.

Comment: But isn't it faster f.e: Instead of having to open a table with 10.000.000 records (10.000 clients X 1.000 messages each - i know the number of records is small, its just an example) just open one SQLite with only 1.000 records? Also with SQLite i save 1 field and index (MySQL will require a field user_id which ofc will be indexed)

Comment: The question is, is it better to use MySQL, which will work on one admittedly big file but probably using buffers and caching, or to work with 10.000 files which you'll have to open and close for every request ? Experiment for yourself, but I'm inclined to believe that the first approach might yield better results.